# Recover name of creator of minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have my minecraft folder with the client and a lot of savegames on my old hard drive, but I dont remember my username and I cant recover my account without it.
So is there any way to get the name from the save files?

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways to recover you username. The MC Launcher should save it. Is it in there? Have you written it down anywhere?

Comment: This seems more like a general Minecraft username recovery question - is that accurate?

Comment: Im on a new system, so the launcher doesnt know the user name, and yes this is a more general question but i thought this could be an easy way to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking the logs in the Minecraft data folder.

Navigate to:

```
C:\Users\[your PC username]\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs
```

In there you'll find a 'latest.log' (and a bunch of archives) and, with any luck, the first line in that log file should look like this:

```
[20:34:03] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: [your minecraft user name]
```

Voila! There's your username. Now you just need to remember the password...